# dimension of a matrix???

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix A:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 &\cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &0 &0 & n\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
So its an $n+1$ by $n+1$ matrix.

Apprently the dimension of this matrix is n+1. But if I find the basis, I keep getting only n elements?

Could someone please justify why the dimension is n+1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know how to type matrices? You should learn it! Have a look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: I don't think you have accounted for the first column of zeros in your calculations.

Comment: The *rank* of the matrix is $n$. I don't know what the dimension means, other than $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ – just by the *shape* of the matrix.

Comment: I only count $n$ rows in your matrix, unless you slipped a hidden one in those dots.

Answer (score 0):

There nothing such as *dimension* defined for a matrix. We can say, that matrix has **rank**. We can define *rank* of a matrix differently, one of the definition works with the number of leading elements (or independent rows/columns) in the matrix.

I am not precise, but let's say that leading element in a matrix is such, that on the same row on the left there are zeros or nothing, and the same for the column beneath it. For example the matrix A:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 &\cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &0 &0 & n\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
has $n$ leading elements, so the rank is equal to $n$. To find out how many leading elements matrix you can use Gauss elimination method (**GEM**).

In our country we denote the rank of the matrix A $h(A)$, in an English speaking countries it might be something like $r(A)$.

---

We talk about **dimension** of a vector space. The **dimension** is defined as the number of base vectors. We often talk about *rank* when we talk about linear mapping between (transformation) two vector spaces, because we can represent such mappings with matrices. We also talk about the *dimension* of the kernel ($\ker \varphi$) and image(Im $\varphi$) of some linear mapping $\varphi$, so both of those terms come in handy.